# PHP upload max file size differently for files under sub folder of views

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, dynamic

Not able to give upload max file size differently for different files under views(Using PHP codeigniter framework).

Tried using .htaccess but applying on all the files.

```
<Files ~ "^(index\.php)$">
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
</Files>
```

If I tried with individual file name not working as full patch cannot be specified for "Files" directive and "Directory" directive cannot be used in .htaccess to specify patch.

```
<Files "test1.php">
    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
</Files>
```

Comment: Your application should probably handle that, it would give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Hey Jeroen, thanks for the response. My application is handling internally but I have to came up with a system level solution cz my application undergoes vulnerability test every quarterly and raised a vulnerability like upload max file size limit is applying entire site wise where we don't need in all the page.So, this is the reason why I am trying to solve fro system level.